# UISteppper connect with textField

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How do I connect `UIstepper` with `textField`?  When I connect it increment and decrement but, when I directly enter number to `textfield` after that try to increment by using stepper the value will start from the `stepper` minimum value. I want to continue from the `textField` value.

Comment: Stepper is a Controller in Xcode 4.2.1 , it is a increment or decrement control.

Answer (score 2):

There is no binding in iOS development like you want.  Basically you have to decide where you want to store your values. You could store your values in the stepper, in the textfield, or in some other variable entirely.

Secondly, but no less importantly, your stepper target function is all wrong. Your problem is that you are re-setting up your stepper each time the `stepperPressed1:` method is fired. Which I hope is connected to your stepper's `valueChanged` event, and I'll assume it is.

Let's for the moment assume that you are trying to store your numerical stepped value in the stepper.

You should be setting up your stepper only once, likely in your `viewDidLoad` method. And then reading the new value when the value changes and writing that to your text field.

For Example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.stepper setMinimumValue:0];
    [self.stepper setContinuous:YES];
    [self.stepper setWraps:NO];
    [self.stepper setStepValue:1];
    [self.stepper setMaximumValue:300];
    self.txtField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",self.stepper.value];
}
-(IBAction)stepperPressed1:(id)sender{
    self.txtField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",self.stepper.value];
}
```

Now as far as setting the value in the stepper based on what is typed in the textfield.  What you need to do is when the user is done typing in a value you want to get that value and assign it to the stepper. You would connect a function to the textField's "Did End On Exit" event. That function would look something like this:

```
-(IBAction)didEndOnExit:(id)sender {
    self.stepper.value = self.txtField.text.doubleValue;
    self.txtField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",self.stepper.value];
}
```

Comment: If get value from the textField then i could't decrement the value.

Comment: If you use the action 'Editing Changed' instead of 'Did End On Exit', and only set the stepper value to the text field value (without the line setting the text field text to the stepper value), the user can now edit the text field with both the stepper and manually.